# need to resize bootstrap dropdown-menu width

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I need to resize my dropdown-menu`s width

this is jsfiddler with the code what I have
[jsfiddler][1]
on this page in the right side on main menu I have languages dropdown menu
when it dropdowns it`s width is veri large
and I need to be like main menu

please help me.

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/giasoft/8cftqmkb/2/
```

Comment: Please add code that is relevant to the question

Comment: this is jsfiddler link https://jsfiddle.net/giasoft/8cftqmkb/1/

Comment: what might this be `width: calc(100% - 50px) !important;` on the .dropdown-menu? Also this is not clear. You say the menu width is _veri large_ and you need it to be like the main menu, which has a larger width that spans the whole page

Comment: No you understand me not correctly
please search class dropdown and in this class is a tag
and I need dropdown menu width to be as this a tag width.

Comment: please see this image http://s020.radikal.ru/i702/1503/29/5d6aba03ab74.png
I need size as here is selected by red line

Comment: So you want the dropdown list to be the same width as the top level menu item that opens the dropdown menu?

Comment: Yep. I need that the dropdown list to be the same width as the top level menu item that opens the dropdown menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

added

```
/* CHANGES */
.dropdown-menu,.dropdown-toggle{
    min-width:100px;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a{
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8cftqmkb/3/

Comment: yes it is what I want
but when I change language in Georgian 
see the image
http://s018.radikal.ru/i525/1503/f6/56751f0bf009.png

Comment: So as I understand I need to change width with jquery.
but I do not know how.

Answer (score 0):

OH everithing is good.
I write little js code to check widths

```
var menuwidth = $('.langs > a').width();
    if(menuwidth > 75) {
        $('.navbar-darkblue .tmenu .dropdown-menu>li>a').css({
            'padding-left': (100 - menuwidth) + 'px',
            'padding-right': (100 - menuwidth) + 'px'
        });
    }
```

and now it works fine...

thank you All